# What's the meaning of "direct" here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Consider the following quote:

> When a pipe carries water, or a wire carries electricity, it contains and **directs** the flow of the water or the electricity.

Is *direct* here sense 2 from [OALD](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/direct_2)?

> 2 [transitive] to control or be in charge of somebody/something

Comment: It's basically the same as _direction_; if the pipe goes south, the water goes south. Check out [Wordnik](http://www.wordnik.com/words/direct), where you'll find: **direct** (v.) _to cause to move toward a goal; to aim; to show or indicate the way for; to cause to move in or follow a straight course_. I think all of these describe water being directed by a plumbing system to some extent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have [OALD](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/direct_2), but here is [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/direct?s=t):

> direct
>   verb (used with object)
>   ...2. to regulate the course of; control: *History is directed by a small number of great men and women.*